# Validation Rule not working properly as per the Requirement

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Need a small help, i am trying to create a validation rule on a lead object - the requirement is whenever the lead status is converted to "Closed - Not Converted" it should throw an error on description, i have created a formula, but its not working, below is the formula

IF( AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Closed - Not Converted")), LEN (Description)>0),true, false)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting your requirement correctly, you need `Description` field to be populated when a Lead is converted to `Closed - Not Converted` stage.

The validation rule which you have written will fire when the status is not equal to `Closed - Not Converted` and Length of `Description` field is greater than `0`, which I hope is not what you want.

From your requirement, you need a validation rule which will fire when status is `Closed - Not Converted` and length of `Description` is not greater than `0`. 
Below validation rule should work for you

```
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Closed - Not Converted"), NOT(LEN(Description)>0)),true, false)
```

Comment: yes it worked, thank you Mr Vijay:)